# vim limited line memory

Tags: vim, lines, pasting

im trying to copy 300 lines from one file to another,
in source file i type "300yy", it says it has yanked 300 lines.

go to destination file and press p,
it pastes, but only the first 50 lines.

any idea why it isn't pasting the 300?

Comment: Does `echo @"` echo all your lines? How do you go to destination file (in this vim instance, or in other)? If you want to save this 300 lines across vim sessions, then you need to modify your viminfo variable as suggested by @eugene y (though you should just remove `,<100` and `,s10` parts of the string). In my vim moving 2800 lines in one vim session works just fine.

Comment: And please paste your version info.

Comment: im on vim 7.2, removing the ,<100 and ,s10 did the trick.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

To see the current settings during a vim session, run:

```
:set viminfo?
```

As suggested in [Vim Tips Wiki](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Copy,_cut_and_paste), you can adjust the [`viminfo`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/options.txt.html#%27viminfo%27) setting (again, during a vim session) by running the ex-command:

```
:set viminfo='100,<1000,s100,h
```

or you can remove the `:` and set it as default in your `.vimrc` as:

```
set viminfo='100,<1000,s100,h
```

What the individual parts mean:

- `'100` Marks will be remembered for the last 100 edited files.
- `<1000` Limits the number of lines saved for each register to 1000 lines; if a register contains more than 1000 lines, only the first 1000 lines are saved.
- `s100` Registers with more than 100 KB of text are skipped.
- `h` Disables search highlighting when Vim starts.

Comment: do you know what each one of those '100,<100,s10,h lines mean?

Comment: this is a vastly superior documentation of the solution to those problems.

Comment: Just a quick note that ":help viminfo" and ":help 'viminfo'" pull up different helps. The latter is the one that you need.

Comment: What does this set the limit to?

Comment: @franka As stated in the :help 'viminfo', < indicates the "Maximum number of lines saved for each register." The default is 50 and in the answer above it is increased to 100.

Comment: Viminfo gives you the following
<\n>
      :set viminfo='50,<1000,s100,:0,n~/vim/viminfo
<
        '50             Marks will be remembered for the last 50 files you
                        edited.
        <1000           Contents of registers (up to 1000 lines each) will be
                        remembered.
        s100            Registers with more than 100 Kbyte text are skipped.
        :0              Command-line history will not be saved.

Comment: when I use `set set viminfo='100,<1000,s100,h` in my `vimrc`, everytime I startup vim, it shows me the setting `viminfo='100,<1000,s100,h` and asks me to press enter. Is there a reason why?

Comment: @alpha_989 the first command was displaying the current setting, which was running every time you started vim. I've edited the answer to be clearer about how you can supply this as a setting (it was copied directly from the VimTips wiki). I've gone with `s200` rather than `s100`

Answer (score 10):

As Eugene and Zyx said adjusting your viminfo would be the easiest solution

`:set viminfo-=<50,s10`

An alternate solution would be use `:read` and/or `:write`

To read in from file-name.txt into the current buffer

`:read file-name.txt`

To append the range of line 1 to line 300 from the current buffer to file-to-append.txt

`:1,300write >> file-to-append.txt`

You can also use marks instead of line numbers such as the visual marks

`:'<,'>write >> file-to-append.txt`

Of course appending may not be able to fulfill your use case in which the viminfo changes will probably work best.

```
:help :write
:help :read
:help 'viminfo'
:help :set-=
```

Comment: before switching from vi to vim I set the following abbrevation (don't remember why I used ab instead of map) :  `cab wbf w! ~/.lastbuffer` and  `rbf r ~/.lastbuffer` which respectively write and read always the same file. Then just do `:wbf` and `:rbf`

Comment: @Peter, wondering why it is important to take `<50,s10` out of viminfo.. rather than just setting viminfo with `set viminfo='100,<1000,s100,h`?

Comment: Just depends on what each person wants set. Nothing wrong with setting it fully. That being said if more options are added in the future it could be a bit trickier

Answer (score 6):

Stay in the same session (open the new file doing :e path) and you won't have any limitation.

Answer (score 5):

try `vim -p file1 file2`. It opens each file into a new tab (which is awesome), and it solves the copy/paste limit

Comment: I've already solved the problem without mandating any new behavior, but thanks.

Comment: Thanks! that was really helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Something that worked for me is, when in visual mode, copying with a command like `:1,300y` that copies from line 1 to 300. You can switch this to any range of lines that you would like as `:37,456y` to copy from line 37 to 456.

If your vim is not showing the lines, you can set the lines with the command `:set numbers`

If you want to use that yanked/copied lines in another file, i recommend opening multiples tabs and copying and pasting the info between them.
To do this you can open them in the terminal with the command `vim -p file1 file2`.
To navigete between them you can use the commands `gt` and `gT` to move to the next and previous tab respectively.